# No Data is Deployed on this contract address, no admin page

Tags: mist

I am following this tutorial to create the My advanced token using this tutorial: https://ethereum.org/token

When I deploy the contract, I always get "No data is deployed on the contract"

I am running a private blockchain and I have tried 8 times the gas suggested by Mist. If I go too much further, it says block limit excited.

[image]

Comment: put 0.00 ETHERs at moment to create the contract

Comment: change the constructor to function MyToken(
        uint256 initialSupply
        ) public payable { .....
    }